# Can git rm take a regex or can I pipe the contents of a file to git rm?

Tags: regex, bash, git

I'm trying to remove all of the folder meta files from a unity project in the git repo my team is using. Other members don't delete the meta file associated to the folder they deleted/emptied and it's propagating to everyone else. It's a minor annoyance that shouldn't need to be seen so I've added this to the .gitignore:

```
*.meta
!*.*.meta
```

and now need to remove only the folder metas. I'd rather remove the metas now than wait for them to appear and have git remove them later. I'm using git bash on Windows and have tried the following commands to find just the folder metas:

```
find . -name '*.meta' > test.txt             #returns folders and files
find . -regex '.*\.meta' > test.txt          #again folders and files
find . -regex '\.[^\.]{0,}\.meta' > test.txt #nothing
find . -regex '\.[^.]{0,}\.meta' > test.txt  #nothing
find . -regex '\.{2}' > test.txt             #nothing
find . -regex '(\..*){2}' > test.txt         #nothing
```

I know regex is interpreted differently per program/language but the following will produce the results I want in Notepad++ and I'm not sure how to translate it for git or git bash:

```
^.*/[^.]{0,}\.meta$
```

by capturing the lines (file paths from root of repo) that end with a `/<foldername>.meta` since I realized some folders contained a '.' in their name.
Once this is figured out I need to go line by line and `git rm` the files.

**NOTE**
I can also run:

```
^.*/.*?\..*?\.meta$\n
```

and replace with nothing to delete all of the file metas from the folders and files result, and use that result to get all of the folder metas, but I'd also like to know how to avoid needing Notepad++ as an extra step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to express with two conditions just like in `.gitignore`. Match `*.meta` but exclude `*.*.meta`:

```
find . -name '*.meta' ! -name '*.*.meta'
```

Use `-exec` to run the command of your choice on the matched files. `{}` is a placeholder for the file names and `';'` signifies the end of the `-exec` command (weird syntax but it's useful if you append other things after the `-exec ... ';'`).

```
find . -name '*.meta' ! -name '*.*.meta' -exec git rm {} ';'
```

Answer (score 2):

To confine the results only to indexed files use `git ls-files`, the swiss-army knife of index-aware file listing.  `git update-index` is the core-command index munger,

```
git ls-files -i -x '*.meta' -x '!*.*.meta' | git update-index --force-remove --stdin
```

which will remove the files from your index but leave them in the work tree.